# Can all plants be reproduced through vegetative propagation?

Tags: botany, reproduction, asexual-reproduction, vegetation

I have learned that plants can be reproduced or propagated through vegetative parts but there is a question in my mind if we can each method for all  types of plants. I don't know if all  plants have cells which can proliferate and differentiate into other tissue types. Do these vegetative parts have such ability. Is it true for all of them?

Can we grow all type of plants from all vegetative parts( i.e, roots, stem and leaves)?

Comment: We ask that questions here show some evidence of prior research; as-is, your question is exceedingly broad. Can you share what you've learned already? What's the purpose of the question?

Comment: A point to start your research which challenges the assumptions that you're questioning would be [chlorella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorella) - a single celled genus of algae with no differentiated cell types.